# I m not getting Dms console.log on discord.js npmjs plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The `console.log()` in the `"messageCreate"` event is not firing when sending a DM.

```
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "DIRECT_MESSAGES"
    ]
})

Client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
   msgArray = msg.content.toLowerCase().split(' ')

   if (msgArray[0] == "/botmsg"){
    Client.users.fetch(msgArray[1], false).then((user) => {
        user.send(msgArray[2]);
       });
   } else {
    console.log(msg.content);
   }
})

Client.login('token hidden')
```

My goal is to log the message when a DM is received, how can I do this?

Comment: `console.log()` is only called if your if-statement is false, are you accurately testing this logic?

Comment: i tried with both didnt work

Comment: Are you sure the bot is properly connected ? And also that you saved your file before restarting your script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With discord.js v13 you need to enable the partial `CHANNEL`, so your Client must be

```js
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "DIRECT_MESSAGES"
    ],
    partials: [
        "CHANNEL"
    ]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put your `console.log` function in the "true" part of code.

```
if (msgArray[0] == "/botmsg"){
    Client.users.fetch(msgArray[1], false).then((user) => {
        user.send(msgArray[2]);
    });
    console.log(msg.content);
} else {
    console.log(msg.content);
}
```

Comment: It didnt work .

Comment: Can you please to @BlindJade _how_ it didn't work (e.g. said `undefined`, threw an error, etc)? Thanks!